# Desagrupar código em uma só linha

Tags: jquery, html, minificação, ofuscação

Galera, alguém sabe como desagrupar códigos que é em uma linha só ? Por que pra deixar em uma linha é fácil, tem alguns softwares que oferece isso, mas desagrupar que só martelando kkkk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você certamente está olhando para um código [`minificado`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)).

Para desminifica-lo, você vai precisar de um programa conhecido como `desminificador`, `code beautifier` ou [`Prettyprint`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint).

Esse [site](https://codebeautify.org/jsviewer) possui um "embelezador" de código `javascript` *on-line*.

Esse [aqui](http://unminify.com/) também pode resolver seu problema.

**EDIT:**

Não é necessário desminificar os códigos da biblioteca `jquery`.

Nessa [página](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/) você vai encontrar ambas as versões: a minificada e a original (*uncompressed*).